# Set conditional color and pattern for highcharter column chart

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to create a column chart where only the last column has a pattern (for year 2020 in the example below) and the rest of the columns have a solid fill. I know about the pattern fill module which can be added with `hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js")` but I'm struggling to make it work for my chart. In fact, I can't even change the default (solid) colors to custom colors. I would really appreciate your help! Thanks so much!

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(cbind(seq(2001, 2020, by=1),
                       sample(1:15, size=20, replace=T),
                       sample(1:15, size=20, replace=T))) 
colnames(df) <- c("year", "newA", "newB")

  highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_add_series(
      name = "New A",
      data = df$newA,
      stack = "new",
      showInLegend = F) %>%
    hc_add_series(
      name = "New B",
      data = df$newB,
      stack = "new",
      showInLegend = F) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$year, title = list(text = ""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, a column chart is created with a single series of data. Only the last column (for 'Day 3') is filled with a pattern, as specified in the hc_add_series() function. For this column, instead of providing just a value, we provide a list containing the value ('y') and the color specification:

```
library(highcharter)

Column_with_stripe <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'), tickmarkPlacement = "on") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Value")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line = list (datalabels = list(enabled = TRUE), enableMouseTracking = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Var1", 
    data = list(
      5, # Day 1
      8, # Day 2
      list(y = 10, color = list(pattern = list(path = 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11', width = 5, height = 5, color = '#f00'))) # Day 3
    ),
    color = "black"
  )

print(Column_with_stripe)
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! How can you modify this code to produce a stacked column chart? I tried just adding another series and including series = list(stacking = "normal")) in the plot options, but it ignores the latter and creates a grouped column chart instead. Thanks again!

Comment: Add like this:
 hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Value")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Var1", 
    data = list(
      2,
      list(y = 4, color = list(pattern = list(path = 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11', width = 10, height = 10, color = 'red'))) # Day 5
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = "Var2",
    data = list(
      3,
      list(y = 5, color = list(pattern = list(path = 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11', width = 10, height = 10, color = 'red'))) # Day 5
    )
  )